# how can i change my application trust level to medium level?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hosting, medium-trust

I bought an hosting provides medium trust level. And i try to make a web site. i couldn't make it work in my host location.

I change the trust level in the iis manager. I deploy the project and tried again but none of them is working.

I tried `<trust level="Medium" originUrl=""/>` and it is not working.
Also i tried that.

```
<location allowOverride=”true”>
<system.web>
<securityPolicy>
<trustLevel name=”Medium” policyFile=”web_mediumtrust.config” />
</securityPolicy>
</system.web>
</location>
```

This is working in my local but not working in hosting.

This is the problem i have.

```
[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +96
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +80
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +288
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm, SecurityAction action) +70
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid() +12
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection ps) +2045
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash() +107
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64 cachedHash) +458
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64 cachedHash) +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549
```

I don't know what i change in here. I change my iis trust level to medium. And working. So what else can i do to fix this? please help me!

Comment: Please kindly contact your hosting provider to give the permission for you. Although you setup it on your code, but it is not allowed with your provider, then it won't work. Or you can find hosting provider that support full trust, like asphostportal. I use them too.

Comment: thanks Mark. I did :) refund my money and changed my hosting provider in the end.